# Misconfigured App Sorry, myapp hasn't been approved for display in App Center. in android app share

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

When i click on my app name on my facebook. It redirect to "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=827708240586758"  and showing "Misconfigured App Sorry, myapp hasn't been approved for display in App Center." .. I think facebook have implemented some new features. Please help me to get out from this problem. Thanks

Comment: have u found solution? i am facing same problem. thanks

Comment: Not yet got solution for this problem:-(. let u no once i got solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
You need to submit your app for review on the Status & Review tab (on https://developers.facebook.com/ site) if you want it to be considered for listing in Facebook - App Center.

1. Log in to the https://developers.facebook.com/ site with your credentials and find your app.
2. [Click on Status & Review tab, and choose Items in Review.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WXDk.png)
3. [Then click on "Add items to this Submission" and select "App Details" from the list and click on the Add Items button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcDve.png)
4. If you are missing some required data from the App Details, there will be red exclamation mark, so you will need to fill in these fields and submit your app again.

Comment: Thanks nikoladev... i completed all those things. waiting for approval from facebook.

Comment: No problem.. When you get approval from FB , if this solves your problem, please accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: Is this also recommended approach for apps that are used only for Facebook OAuth integration on websites ?

Comment: Me too have the same issue. My app was on the store and today when I am checking it has popped out the above error. Is there any way i can find from when this issue occurred and why it has happened?

Comment: It says games only. "if you want to make your non-game app live (in production), flip the switch at the top of the App Review tab." I cant locate the the switch he is talking about.

Answer (score 13):

I stumbled across a solution that worked for my case. I simply wanted the app name in the feed to link to the App Store and not this misconfigured app page! The simple solution is to go to Settings, Add Platform of type Website and put a link to the App Store there.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Helpful. Took me a while to find the actual 'add platform' interface though!